# Fitting lognormal distribution from D10, D50, and D90

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, normal-distribution, median

I have a statistical sample where D10 = 8 (10% of population under the value 8), D50 = 11 (median), and D90 = 18 (90% of population under de value 18)

Now, I need to fit the $\mu$ and the $\sigma^2$ of a probability distribution given these values. Judging from the different distance of D10, and D90, from D50, I would discard the normal distribution. I think its more similar to a lognormal one.

Any help is highly appreciated

Comment: If it came from log-normal, log(8), log(11) and log(18) would fit a normal distribution. However, log(8) and log(18) are not exactly equidistant from log(11), so I assume you are looking for a good fit, eg maximum likelihood estimate of mu and sigma?

Comment: Yes, I am looking for the best fit. I tried to do a linear regression of log(8), log(11), log(18). And use the slope as the standard deviation and the intersection in x=0 as the mean. But the probability distribution I get does not represent my sample values.